# Deconvolution Between Matrix and Sub Matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution, deconvolution

I have a matrix `a=[[1 2 3]; [4 5 6]; [7 8 9]]` and a submatrix `b=[[5 6];[8 9]]`.

Is there a method in matlab for deconvolving `(a,b)` ?

I am looking for a method fo recognize the presence of a submatrix in a possible giant matrix. By a sort of deconvolution I expect to obtain something like a matrix with zeros all around and `1` in the place where the submatrix is present.

In the above example, a `1` in the right-down corner.

Comment: It's really unclear where convolution entered the discussion.  Are you saying that you have a matrix `c=conv2(a,b)` and you want to literally deconvolve?  If not can you use a more accurate term than "deconvolve"?  Seems that this is just finding a submatrix within a matrix.

Comment: O.K. There are 2 problems in one. The first one is about matlab. If I have `c=conv2(a,b)`, how can I recover b by deconvolving c and a ? The second one is more "philosophical". Suppose `a` is the result of interaction (convolution) between objects. Suppose you do not know these objects. Just model a representation of one of them. I would like to apply a sort of deconvolution between `a` (the big picture) and my hypothetical representation of an object. My goal is to obtain a matrix (with the same size as `a`), with ones where/if the object could be present in `a`.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those two questions came across clearly. Ask more precise questions if you actually want answers.

Comment: Also check out : http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/deconvolution-of-1d-signals/3560#3560

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a better explanation [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/deconvolution-of-1d-signals/3560#3560).

---

Let's talk about 1D deconvolution for simplicity sake.

Your signal can be represented as a vector, and convolution is multiplication with a tridiagonal matrix.

For example:

Your vector/signal is:

```
    V1
    V2
    ...
    Vn
```

Your filter (convolving element) is:

```
  [b1 b2 b3];
```

So the matrix is `nxn`: (Let it be called `A`):

```
[b2 b3 0  0  0  0.... 0]
[b1 b2 b3 0  0  0.... 0]
[0  b1 b2 b3 0  0.... 0]
.....
[0  0  0  0  0  0...b2 b3]
```

Convolution is:

```
  A*v;
```

And de-convolution is

```
  A^(-1) * ( A) * v;
```

Obviously, in some cases de-convolution is not possible. Then you will have singular `A`.
But if `A^-1` exists, you need to compute it, and apply it on the result.

---

For 2D case, it is a bit more complex, but the idea is the same.

Comment: `A` seems like a Toeplitz matrix. It is known that if we have two signals `a` and `b`, `c=conv2(a,b)=A*b'`, where `A` is the toeplitz matrix of `a`. The problem is that the # of columns of `A` have to be equal to the # of columns of `b`, and `A` has to be square if we want to deconvolve `c,A` by `b'=A^-1*c`. It is not so clear to me how manipulate these sizes...

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, A is square - it is the size of the signal in both dimensions. The filter size is the amount of non-zero diagonals.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the presence, or the likelihood of presence, of small matrix inside another, then you're looking for correlation, not deconvolution.

The simplest method would be to use `normxcorr2`, which return a matrix of values [-1..1], where 1 means the pixel where the small matrix is found.

The drawback/benefit is that normxcorr2 is not sensitive to gain, meaning if you're looking for [1 2 3 4] then you'll also find [2 4 6 8]